# Istio upgrade from HELM to istioctl

Tags: microservices, kubernetes-helm, istio

I'm little confused with the istioctl manifest migrate command for upgrading from 1.4.3 > 1.4.10.

The installation is done with HELM with version 1.4.3 and following method.

```
helm template --name istio-init install/kubernetes/helm/istio-init --namespace istio-system | kubectl apply -f -
helm template --name istio-init \
    --set kiali.enabled=true \
    ## all specs defined#
    ./install/kubernetes/helm/istio --namespace istio-system \
    --values ./install/kubernetes/helm/istio/values-istio-sds-auth.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Now, before upgrade to 1.4.10, I have to create the istioctl manifest migrate with following command from 1.4.3 installation directory, right?

```
./bin/istioctl manifest migrate ./install/kubernetes/helm/istio/values.yaml > istio-migrate.yaml
./bin/istioctl manifest migrate ./install/kubernetes/helm/istio/values-istio-sds-auth.yaml > istio-migrate.yaml
```

But, this command just returns:

```
proto: tag has too few fields: "-"
```

Does this command complete successfully?
if yes, which file should I pass as -f while I'll be in 1.4.10 directory and use the istioctl upgrade command?
if no, how can I correctly generate the manifest file?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using a very old version of Istio? Current version is 1.11.3

Comment: old version is running currently and not updated since long.